# Devise username validation during sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise, model

I added validation to my user.db and when I try to sign up it doesn't really work. When I don't enter the username, it says that that field can't be blank - which is correct. However, if the field is filled in, it still says that the field can't be blank and doesn't allow me to register. This is my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

validates :name,
  :presence => true,
  :uniqueness => {
    :case_sensitive => false
  }

  has_many :pins
end

#:recoverable
```

View

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>

<div align='center'>
    <h2>Sign up</h2><br>



    <div class='field_center'>
        <%= f.input :name %>
        <%= f.input :email %>
        <%= f.input :password %>
        <%= f.input :password_confirmation %>
    </div>

      <div class="form-actions">
        <%= f.submit "Sign Up", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
      </div>

    <% end %>
    <br>
    <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using a custom view for the log in page? If so, could you post it?

Comment: It's not a custom log in page, it's generated by Devise. However, I edited it a bit. I assume you meant the registration view - added.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if it's going to be helpful, but can you please check what parameters are sent at the POST action at the shell running the web server? Make sure the params are sent for :name attribute and they're not empty.

If the params for name are really empty in web server log, check your view. I had a similar case when a unclosed tag in erb resulted in a weird behavior with Devise (empty params as well).